# vba Selenium. Доступ к скрытым спискам

Tags: selenium, vba

Заполняю данные на сайте при помощи селениума. Форма сделана так, что после ответа на один вопрос появляется выпадающий список со следующим. Селениум не видит этот скрытый список не до ответа на первый вопрос ни после. Реально же он есть в коде страницы.
Как же до него достучаться?

Comment: Зачем вам селениум?

Comment: Как зачем? Я же выше написал - заполняю данные на сайте через него.

Comment: То, что вы видите - это интерфейс, лишь оболочка, созданная для удобного общения с сервером. Зачем вам оболочка, если можно общаться напрямую с сервером? Всякие кнопочки, формы и прочее, это POST/GET (и др.) запросы на сервер с определенными данными. Так вопрос у меня тот же, зачем вам селениум? Почему вы работаете с интерфейсом, а не сервером?